# how to use IntegrationFlowContext as part of process configuration?

Tags: spring-integration

as part of my spring-boot process configuration, I create multiple very similar integration flows.
My current config code looks like below:

```java
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {

    @Component
    public static class FlowFactory {
        public IntegrationFLow createFlow(String someValue) {
            return IntegrationFLows.from
            ...
            .get();
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow flow1(FlowFactory flowFactory) {
        return flowFactory.createFlow("1");
    } 
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow flow2(FlowFactory flowFactory) {
        return flowFactory.createFlow("2");
    } 
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow flow3(FlowFactory flowFactory) {
        return flowFactory.createFlow("3");
    } 

}
```

How can I replace (in my configuration class) those hard-coded beans with a registration loop making use of IntegrationFlowContext ?
Maybe Something like below ?

```java
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {

    @Component
    public static class FlowFactory {

        FlowFactory(IntegrationFlowContext flowContext) {
            for (String someValue : ImmutableList.of("1","2","3") {
                flowContext.registration(createFLow(someValue)).register();    
            }
        }

        private IntegrationFLow createFlow(String someValue) {
            return IntegrationFLows.from
            ...
            .get();
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks a lot in advance for your time and your expertise.
Best Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use an `IntegrationFlowContext` like that, but it would be better to do that 
`register()` in the `@PostConstructor`: there are many factors which may effect how we register beans, so would be better to defer a flow registration as far as possible.

So, in my mind it is like this:

```java
@Component
public static class FlowFactory {
    private final IntegrationFlowContext flowContext;

    FlowFactory(IntegrationFlowContext flowContext) {
        this.flowContext = flowContext;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        for (String someValue : ImmutableList.of("1","2","3") {
            this.flowContext.registration(createFLow(someValue)).register();    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much to both of you Gary and Artem for taking time to reply to grass-root level end-users like me !